# Get info of authenticated user (not computer name)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a login page and it calls following event handler:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{        
    if (Login1.UserName == "abc" && Login1.Password == "1234"){
        if (Request["ReturnUrl"] != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false, "AdminPart/AdminHome.aspx");
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
        }
        else
        {              
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false, "AdminPart/AdminHome.aspx");
            Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
        }
    }    
}
```

And my web.config file is like this:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

Now, I'm trying to get authenticated user's user name in my HomePage.aspx.cs, but `User.Identity.Name` returns the name of my computer. I tried to add following code to config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="10" protection="All"></forms>
</authentication>
```

But a problem occured again with the line `<authentication mode="Forms">`. After I add this line, in my HomePage, IDE gave me a warning for the first line starting with `<% Page ... %>` that there would be a runtime error.

I used `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, doesn't work also.
I'm just trying to get the name of authenticated user in different parts of project. So I can change the logic if I have to.
Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: I'm using Visual Web Devepoler 2008 Express, on Windows 7(64-bit).

EDIT2: **Problem resolved** somehow. Answer is below. How? Why? Can't it be done programitically? I don't know and I wanna know why.

Comment: User.Identity.Name might be empty if Anonymous Authentication is enabled in IIS. Whats the result of this `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` ?

Comment: It's true. But something totally awkward occured, I'm updating the post now.

Comment: Since my reputation is low I have 2 hours to answer my question. Till then I edited the question.

Comment: I upvoted you, didn't realise the 2 hour rule. Dont worry tho with the quality of your questions/troubleshooting it wont be till your points go up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found: first, I removed the authorization tag in `web.config` file. Then in solution explorer window, I clicked `Properties` icon and a configuration web page for ASP.NET opened. Then I clicked `Security tab->Set up authentication`. I chose the option with Internet connection, now I can reach the authenticated user name by `Page.User.Identity.Name` anywhere.